# Changing the image path after images were uploaded

Tags: 7

I have created a image field under a custom Content Type and let the file directory setting to default, meaning the files are not uploaded to any sub directory.

As I can see now this is not a suitable situation for me and I would like to save the files in a sub directory. If I change the File Directory setting under the Field Settings will this break the paths of the files uploaded prior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change the File Directory setting under the Field Settings will this break the paths of the files uploaded prior?

Yes

As i think you need to go a two step process.

1. Move the images to the new folder.
2. Update the existing image path in database.

Before moving with any process keep all the backups.

Refer these links which may help you to move

[seeking advice on changing file system path after files have been upload](https://www.drupal.org/node/258099)

[Moving the files directory](https://www.drupal.org/node/76924)

Comment: Even though your answer was spot on I had done my job with [File Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths). I could't work around your answer because my files were exceeding the count limit of a folder under my hosting account and therefore I had to find a way to split up my files in different folders. Thanks anyway.